# Echo certain value from an array - PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to echo certain value from cURL request.

My PHP code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.envato.com/v1/market/new-files:themeforest,site-templates.json',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: Bearer myuniquekeygoeshere')
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
echo $resp;

curl_close($curl);
```

When I use `echo $resp` I'm getting this (this is the screenshot from their API but I'm getting the same so it works well so far):
[image]

How can I echo certain value from this - lets say "Emanate - Startup Landing Page"?

I've tried `echo $resp["new-files"][0]["item"];` but instead of name I'm getting `{` and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you are getting is a JSON. You have to do something like this:

```
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$respArray = json_decode($resp, true);
$item = $respArray['new-files'][0]['item'];
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could decode the json and access to the proper index  in the array

eg for the firts occurrence of item

```
$my_array = json_decode($resp, true);

echo $my_array['new-files][0]['item'];
```

Comment: `json_decode($resp, true);` in order to have as output an associative array.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting response in JSON so need to decode JSON to Array after that you can use this, try once

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.envato.com/v1/market/new-files:themeforest,site-templates.json',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: Bearer myuniquekeygoeshere')
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($resp, true);
print_r($response);

curl_close($curl);
```